# Write an installation path without a drive letter to INI file in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I do not know how to remove the drive letter from the folder path in `IDPath` and all subsequent lines.

This is how the code of these sections looks like in [INI] right now:

```
[INI]
Filename: "{app}\game.ini"; Section: "Nancy Data"; Key: "CDDrive1";  \
  String: "{drive:{src}}\"; Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist
Filename: "{app}\game.ini"; Section: "Nancy Data"; Key: "CDDrive2"; \
  String: "{drive:{src}}\"; Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist
Filename: "{app}\game.ini"; Section: "Nancy Data"; Key: "HDDrive"; \
  String: "{drive:{src}}"; Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist
Filename: "{app}\game.ini"; Section: "Nancy Data"; Key: "IDPath"; \
  String: "{app}\Нэнси Дрю. Секреты могут убивать"; Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist
Filename: "{app}\game.ini"; Section: "Nancy Data"; Key: "CifTreePath"; \
  String: "{app}\Нэнси Дрю. Секреты могут убивать\ciftree\"; \
  Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist
```

Here's what's being created:

```
[Nancy Data]
CDDrive1=C:
CDDrive2=C:
HDDrive=C:
IDPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Нэнси Дрю. Секреты могут убивать
CifTreePath=C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Нэнси Дрю. Секреты могут убивать\ciftree\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) to customize the value:

```
[INI]
Filename: "{app}\game.ini"; Section: "Nancy Data"; Key: "IDPath"; \
  String: "{code:RemoveDrive|{app}\Нэнси Дрю. Секреты могут убивать}"; \
  Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist
```

```pascal
[Code]

function RemoveDrive(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := Param;

  if (Length(Result) >= 3) and (Result[2] = ':') and (Result[3] = '\') then
    Result := Copy(Result, 3, Length(Result) - 2);
end;
```

Results in:

```
[Nancy Data]
IDPath=\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Нэнси Дрю. Секреты могут убивать
```